# What is mate rescue in bwa mem?

Tags: read-mapping, bwa

BWA mem has the `-S` and `-P` tags for *skip mate rescue* and *skip pairing; mate rescue performed unless -S also in use*.

What do these do? I presume `-P` aligns read pairs independently of each other. Is that correct?

And what does `-S` do?

Comment: What version of BWA mem are you using?  Have you looked at the manual that gets installed with bwa?  "Please `man ./bwa.1' for the manual."

Comment: 0.7.17; I did look at the manual page but the explanation is somewhat cryptic: _"-P: In the paired-end mode, perform SW to rescue missing hits only but do not try to find hits that fit a proper pair."_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `-SP` is equivalent to running `bwa mem` on each of the two mates as if they are single-end reads, but it formats the output as a proper paired-end output, i.e. with all pair-related flags added properly. Without `-SP`, by default `bwa mem` forces an alignment of a poorly aligned read if its mate is aligned somewhere. `-SP` turns off the forced alignment. We use `-SP` for mapping Hi-C reads.

Answer (score 2):

If one read maps and the other doesn't, BWA attempts to rescue the other read by performing Smith-Waterman alignment with the unmapped mate, `-S` disables this mate rescue.

`-P` does indeed disables pairing, but mate rescues is still enabled - I think `-P` disables the setting of the proper pair flag. If you set `-P` and `-S`, BWA maps the paired reads essentially as single reads.

Comment: What does "attempts to rescue" mean? Why would the second read map using Smith-Waterman and not using the original algorithm?